# Consuming WCF service from windows ce 5.0

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-ce, webservice-client, .net-cf-3.5

I am experiencing a strange problem. I know there are quite a few questions about WCF around, but I am almost sure I have already seen the majority of them and cant solve my problem yet. The problem is, I have a WCF service up and running on the remote server and I am able to consume it from the program I have written on the motorola mc65 device(OS is Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5). Now I need a slightly different web service on the same server, for another Motorola device, mk4000 kiosk that has Windows ce 5.0 running on it. Both of the devices are using .NET CF 3.5 and since generating the proxy for WCF using NetCFSvcutil worked for first case, I thought I would be able to use the same proxy for Windows ce app, but I am getting this error: This protocol version is not supported and that's all. There no error description in inner exception, too. I have no idea what can be the cause of this message, after a bit of research I found what it means that the server does not support http, but I am able to exchange information via http from another device. I would really appreciate if anyone could at least point me to the right direction about solving this matter :/

Comment: Are you exposing the endpoint over basicHttpBinding?

Comment: @field_b yes, I was using basicHttpBinding. The problem has been solved in the least expected way and I will answer it, in case somebody gets that "protocol version" error, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be pretty funny in the end, once I connect my laptop to the device via usb port, the device cannot connect to anything, ethernet connection just stops and I found out about it pretty randomly, because I had our IT guys check if everything is ok with connection to the server and all was good. I have never thought about checking the connection right after usb connection, as the message was so unclear. I still do not know the exact reasons of this, but still it may help others working with that Motorola MK4000 Micro Kiosk device.